Does DMCA apply to material that isn't for sale to the general public?
My favorite game was threatened with DMCA takedown for using real car models without a license. They haven't actually received a takedown notice, they were threatened with one.
I suggested of making the removed cars on sale for Christmas, but only for the people who have history with owning some cars from said brands.
Is it legal if they aren't practically on sale for everybody, but instead were just for the people who owned them and the brands didn't use DMCA against the game?

Is your question "can a game developer commit a little intellectual property law violation, as a treat?"

Within the US, here are the options that I'm aware of:

By obtaining the necessary licensing the cars could be added back into the game.

The designs could be possible modified in such a way as to invoke the "feeling" of given cars, but differ enough that they wouldn't be considered infringing. The challenge with this approach is that "differ enough" is typically determined by the court system.

A legal decision (either a court case or settlement) allowing use under the 1st Amendment. In AM General LLC v. Activision Blizzard, Inc., S.D.N.Y., No. 17-8644, the court ruled Activision Blizzard could not be sued for trademark infringement for featuring Humvees in Call of Duty, as there use was protected by the First Amendment. The Rogers test, established in the Rogers v. Grimaldi, allows the rejection of trademark infringement claims if the trademark is used for artistic purposes and does not mislead consumers. Apply the test, the court concluded:



If realism is an artistic goal, then the presence in modern warfare games of vehicles employed by actual militaries undoubtedly furthers that goal.

So the game developer could site this case law in response to whomever issued the DMCA threat. It doesn't mean that they won't issue a take down request, but it likely do more to prevent a frivolous lawsuit than doing nothing at all.
To be clear, I'm not saying this does or does not fall under First
Amendment fair use; for that, you'll need to consult with a legal
professional. I'm only stating there's a similar legal precedent that
might be relevant in this situation.
As to the question legality of offering unlicensed game assets even if they aren't "technically for sale" - no. If someone else holds the relevant IP rights, you cannot legally distribute them. Attempting to profit from likely increases the damages that could be sought, but not profiting from it doesn't convert an illegitimate use into a legitimate one.
